# add Horizontal/Vertical Dividing Lines for the exported HTML table

Tags: org-mode, org-table

For example, here's an Org file:

```
| A | B |
| C | D |

| A | B |
|---+---|
| C | C |
```

How to make the exported HTML tables look like:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| C | D |

More specifically, I want these dividing lines:

[image]

Comment: By default html export backend does not draw frame and cell borders for tables. [See this manual page](https://orgmode.org/manual/Tables-in-HTML-export.html) how to do it.

Comment: @Ian: I think it's the best solution.  I will accept it if you make it an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [CSS](https://orgmode.org/manual/CSS-support.html). For example:

```org
#+HTML_HEAD: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />


For example, here's an Org file with two tables:

| A | B |
| C | D |

and

| A | B |
|---+---|
| C | C |
```

with the following style file:

```css
table, th, td {border: 1px solid;}
```

does what you want.

EDIT: you can do the same thing inline in the Org file, but it makes for a very long line as soon as your settings grow in length or number (or both). But it *is* possible:

```org
#+HTML_HEAD: <style>table, th, td {border: 1px solid;}</style>


For example, here's an Org file with two tables:

| A | B |
| C | D |

and

| A | B |
|---+---|
| C | C |
```

Comment: Thx.  Any way to do these things in one single Org file?  I don't want to prepare a separate CSS file.

Comment: Yes, see my edit - although my preference is to always have a separate CSS file, instead of having long lines in the Org file with HTML/CSS/LaTeX content. I prefer to keep the Org file as clean as possible and relegate all the ugly pieces into separate files if possible.

Answer (score 2):

If you can get by with only vertical internal borders, you can do it without any CSS. See [`(info "(org) Column Groups")`](https://orgmode.org/manual/Column-Groups.html), which includes the following example:

```
 | N | N^2 | N^3 | N^4 | sqrt(n) | sqrt[4](N) |
 |---+-----+-----+-----+---------+------------|
 | / |  <  |     |  >  |       < |          > |
 | 1 |  1  |  1  |  1  |       1 |          1 |
 | 2 |  4  |  8  | 16  |  1.4142 |     1.1892 |
 | 3 |  9  | 27  | 81  |  1.7321 |     1.3161 |
 |---+-----+-----+-----+---------+------------|
```

The third row is a non-printing, non-exporting column-formatting declaration. The `<` and `>` cells delimit column groups. From the same page of the manual: "Upon export, boundaries between column groups are marked with vertical lines."

There's no reason not to make each individual column its own column group. There's a shortcut syntax for it, in fact:

```
 | N | N^2 | N^3 | N^4 | sqrt(n) | sqrt[4](N) |
 |---+-----+-----+-----+---------+------------|
 | / |  <  | <   | <   | <       | <        > |
 | 1 |  1  |  1  |  1  |       1 |          1 |
```

What this won't do is give you internal horizontal borders, so that may rule it out for your use case, or you might use CSS just for those.

Comment: Great! This works even for all exported formats.